# WITH AS using UNION and GROUP BY

Tags: sql-server, group-by, union, with-statement

I inherited some convoluted SQL Server code which I am trying to use with new data. What I want to know is if someone was in hospital, got a prescription, or was immunised in 2017; based on their `unique_id`. I'm looking at a variety of tables to find their health system contact, extract relevant events for 2017, and then add on demographic information from `table.dems` and `table.geo`.

I want one line per `unique_id`, showing 1 if they had contact with a hospital, or got a prescription or immunisation; and then their demographic information.

The summary code is:

```
WITH CORE_POP_17 AS
( SELECT unique_id,
         year_num,
         MAX(aaa) as aaa,
         MAX(ccc) as ccc,
         MAX(bbb) as bbb
FROM (
      SELECT unique_id,
             year(event_date) as year_num,
             1 as aaa, 
             0 as ccc, 
             0 as bbb
      FROM table.hosps
      WHERE year_num IN (2017)

      
      UNION

       SELECT unique_id,
             year(event_date) as year_num,
             0 as aaa, 
             1 as ccc, 
             0 as bbb
      FROM table.pharms
      WHERE year_num IN (2017)
      
      UNION

       SELECT unique_id,
             year(event_date) as year_num,
             0 as aaa, 
             0 as ccc, 
             1 as bbb
      FROM table.imms
      WHERE year_num IN (2017)

     )
GROUP BY unique_id
)
SELECT
unique_id, 
aaa,
bbb,
ccc,
dems.rrr,
geo.ppp

FROM CORE_POP_17 CORE_POP
LEFT JOIN table.dems dems
ON dems.unique_id = CORE_POP.unique_id
LEFT JOIN table.geo geo
on geo.unique_ID = CORE_POP.unique_id
```

The GROUP BY command is throwing an error

> "Incorrect syntax near the keyword GROUP"

Any help to get this to work much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Your subqueries (which are derived tables) need to have an alias.  Voting to close as a typo question.

Comment: FYI `WITH AS` is called a CTE or Common Table Expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's missing an alias for the nested inner unioned queries in the parentheses. Something as simple as a single character (any letter at all) immediately following the parentheses just above `GROUP BY` will fix this.

When that is done, you'll also find `year_num` is not valid in the `SELECT` list, because it's not part of the `GROUP BY` or an aggregate function. Since the year is always `2017`, you could either replace this with a string literal or add `yearnum` to the `GROUP BY` list.

That's all I looked for. I haven't paid any attention to whether the logic of the query makes any sense... only the obvious syntactic stuff.